# Docker in Crouton - VFS consuming astronomical amounts of space

Tags: chroot, docker, chrome-os, vfs, aufs

I'm attempting to help out a roommate who has installed Kubuntu on his Chromebook using Crouton (it's basically just a fancy chroot run within ChromeOS).

I helped him get the Docker daemon running, using some advice from this issue on the Docker github: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1863.  That involved using the flag --storage-driver=vfs. AUFS tools are installed according to apt, but I guess there's some additional support that ChromeOS is lacking.

Anyways, the first pull he did failed because it filled the remainder of his SSD (about 8gb). I pulled the same image onto a blank Docker install on my laptop, and the entire /var/lib/docker directory consumed 1.2gb.

Is the fact that we're using vfs causing this? There's a literal order of magnitude difference in storage space used. I'm not overly familiar with Docker, but the other thought I had was that it uses system libraries when available but will pull anything not installed.

TL;DR - Docker image takes up ~700Mb on my machine, over 8Gb on a friend's. We'd like to be able to pull one Docker image without resorting to external storage. Is there anything we can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working through this same issue now. This happens because vfs is not a true union file system (like aufs), so every incremental image in the image you restore is restored to its full size.

See this issue for more details:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14040